# ifelse statement with calculation in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to write code to convert different currencies to EUR.

The current dataset(df) looks like this.

| Currency | Price |
| --- | --- |
| CHF | 1000 |
| DKK | 20000 |

My goal is mutate a column to show how much they are in EUR.

| Currency | Price | EUR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CHF | 1000 | 980 |
| DKK | 20000 | 2600 |

It seems easy but I can't really figure it out...
Can anyone help me with this?

I tried a code with ifelse.

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(converted = ifelse(Currency == "CHF", Price*0.98, 
                      ifelse(Currency == "EUR", Price*1,         
                      ifelse(Currency == "DKK", Price*0.13))))
```

It returns this error message.

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `converted`. [34mℹ[39m `converted = ifelse(...)`. [31m✖[39m non-numeric argument to...

I've also tried this.

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(converted = if(Currency == "CHF"){
    Price*0.98
} else if (Currency == "DKK"){
    Price*0.13
} else {
    Price*1
}
```

It returns another error message.

> Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:9:0: unexpected end of input 7: Price*1 8: } ^

Comment: `case_when` could be a better alternative to those nested `if`-statements.

Comment: Please share a part of your original data using `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: found it, your last ifelse statement needs a FALSE condition, its always ifelse(test, true, false)

Answer (score 0):

### `case_when` vs nested `ifelse`

As mentioned in the replies, `case_when()` will make your code easier to read and write:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Currency, ~Price,
  "CHF", 1000,
  "DKK", 20000
)

euro_prices <- df %>%
  mutate(
    converted = case_when(
      Currency == "CHF" ~ Price * 0.98, 
      Currency == "EUR" ~ Price * 1,         
      Currency == "DKK" ~ Price * 0.13,
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
    )
  )
```

output:
[image: case_when option]

### an alternative that will scale

If you have more currencies though or if you will want to track changes in the rates then it will be more effective to keep your prices and rates each in their own data table and join the rates as needed in order to convert your prices. Something like this:

```
rates <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Currency, ~rate,
  "CHF", 0.98, 
  "EUR", 1,         
  "DKK", 0.13
)

df %>% 
  left_join(rates, by = "Currency") %>% 
  mutate(converted = Price * rate) %>% 
  select(-rate)
```

output:
[image: case_when option]